# Can VAR models capture all frequency interactions reliably and to the same extent?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, reliability, frequency

I would like to assess how a set of ~50-100 time-series variables causally interact with each other. To do this, I am fitting a VAR model and using cross-validation to estimate model-order. After the model is fit, I use partial directed coherence (PDC) to estimate directed causal interactions between variables at various frequency ranges. Looking at these interactions, I find myself wondering whether or not I can be equally confident about the results across frequency ranges. Do there exist any theoretically based arguments on this topic, or is my only option to resort to simulations/empiricism? Is this problem addressed in any papers that people know of? It seems like economists mostly care about impulse responses rather than looking at frequency-dependent causal interactions, which is making it difficult for me to find relevant info.

Comment: Just a heads-up (even though you might know that already): time series cross validation works differently from the cross-sectional cross validation. See Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["Cross-validation for time series"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/) and the paper referenced therein.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I am aware of this, but I am pretty skeptical of how necessary it is. Empirically, my results always seem to be pretty similar across CV approaches.

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting to learn. Perhaps it could be an idea for a piece of academic research to investigate how much one can expect to gain/lose from different CV approaches for time series.